# Agile .NET Code Encryption doesn't seem to work?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Agile .NET's virtualization features since a time, and I have wanted to try their Code Encryption. The obfuscation completes fine, but once I deploy my DLL with It, the application just doesn't work.
I hardly found that the obfuscator will provide you some dlls like AgileDotNetRT and AgileDotNetRT64, in the options, but I don't get any.
I even tried copying those dlls from the install folder without luck.

Anyone knows why? I haven't found any info on the "docs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question, but Encryption doesn't work on mono, which was confirmed by the devs.